Book on Hilbert spaces, including non-separable
I am looking for a book that develops the theory of Hilbert spaces, including the spectral theorems and unitary representations, but includes non-separable Hilbert spaces in the main exposition.  Any special results for separable Hilbert spaces are carefully marked as such, so as not to confuse the main exposition, which includes non-separable Hilbert spaces.

Halmos's Introduction to Hilbert space and the theory of spectral multiplicity is what you are looking for. Since it's published by Dover, the price is very reasonable.

Thanks.  I've ordered the book.  The length of only 120 pages had suggested to me that this would not be a rigorous exposition.  I shouldn't judge a book by its cover! Can't go wrong, though, with the $15 price.
